# for which they mocked me

Tags: grammaticality

a. I slipped and fell, **for which my friends mocked me**.

b. I slipped and fell, **which my friends mocked me for**.

c. I slipped and fell, **which made my friends mock me**.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think they are, but am not sure. This is I think what they call a 'sentential which'. It refers back to the clause that precedes it (I slipped and fell).

Many thanks.

Comment: Some people will tell you that option B is incorrect because you shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition, but they are wrong... all three are acceptable.

Comment: The connection is so clear that you could just say "I slipped and fell, and my friends mocked me."

Comment: The story I heard, which has some credible evidence, is that in the 1800s, there was a "grammar" (a book to learn proper English ***from***) which was the go-to book for all of England. It was highly regarded in all ways, but happened to include the non-rule that "one must not end a sentence with a preposition". The book was gospel, so teachers started beating their students into "fixing" their English, and only let off a couple decades ago. Evidence for this is **Jamaica**. In Jamaican English, you never end a sentence with prepositions because the whole island learned English from that book.

Answer (score 5):

All of those examples are correct.  It used to be considered incorrect to end a sentence with a preposition, like in example b., but I think that is acceptable now.  Example a. sounds very formal and most people wouldn't speak that way, but it is correct.